# generator-gulp-angular: How to add a new module, controller, directive?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've started using **generator-gulp-angular** and it is a nice generator for angular which follows angular 1.3 and higher versions.

After the project generation, I wanted to create a new module and few controllers for customizing the project.

So I've created a folder for module and few files consists templates, controllers, directives and style sheets.

However after running `gulp serve` all the files (controllers, directives) that I've defined are becoming undefined and styles are not at all applying.

---

> How can I add a new module to the existing application which was generated by generator-gulp-angular.

Is there anything do I need to do to add new files(controllers, directives, style sheets)?

if yes could anyone share the procedure of how to add a new module?

---

NOTE: I've tried to add controller, directive files to index.module.js, styles to index.less and it is working fine.

However we shouldn't do in this way as all the controllers, directives will be in single file :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator-gulp-angular-subtask to add new modules.

Install it with npm.

```
npm install -g generator-gulp-angular-subtask
```

Then configure it by running `yo gulp-angular-subtask`.

Then you can create new modules like below.

```
yo gulp-angular-subtask:factory menu
```

Above command will create a menu factory.

Answer (score 0):

by writing `yo` you would get all the generators that you have installed, and you could execute any one that you need :

```
You can see each generator subtask's options typing:
yo gulp-angular-subtask:controller --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:directive --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:provider --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:factory --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:service --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:value --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:constant --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:filter --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:style --help
yo gulp-angular-subtask:partial --help
```

These are the available generators that gulp-angular has got.